# How to quantify whether a sampling is truly random

Tags: statistics

The problem I have been thinking about is this:

Say we have a fact that F = 56% of gamblers wear sunglasses indoors, and that there are exactly N = 20,345 gamblers.  Now say I pay a company to take a random sample as an exercise to confirm the value of F. The company takes a sample of S = 73 gamblers and finds that G = 62% of them wear sunglasses indoors. Say I discover later that the company also sells sunglasses, and so may have an incentive to inflate the numbers.  How would I know if G is within some non-suspicious range of values given that the true value is F?  In other words, what range of values for G given a sample of size S for population of size N would be statistically non-suspect, knowing that the actual value is F?

Comment: This seems similar to the $p$-value concept of statistics.

Comment: I looked into this, and I was uncertain as to how to calculate a p-value for this case.  Do you have any idea?

Comment: Wow...that's an amazingly clearly formulated question for someone who doesn't have any idea about the answer, with oddly specific values given.

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of your comment, John.  Am I being accused of something?  I try to ask clear questions. I thought that was something people desired on this site.

Comment: @Karlton : I think John's comment is just expressing frustration that this seems to be a homework problem, in which case I have inadvertently given you a solution that you can copy.

Comment: @JohnHughes : I understand your concern.  Usually I don't give solutions to homework-like problems.  In this case there seemed to be a variety of approaches (some may or may not account for repetitions in the samples)  so I wanted to know for myself how accurate a Gaussian approx would be against the exact.  As I mentioned in my comment, I am amazed that a continuity correction seems to be so accurate.

Comment: Ah, I see.  No, this problem is not homework.  I am an educator, not a student.  However, my field is not statistics!  The problem I am really interested has to do with statistics being tossed around in the current discussion happening around race in the US.  I was hoping to avoid the emotional charge by obscuring the subject as something benign so that we could just discuss mathematics.

Comment: @Karlton : That is very interesting context for your problem, thanks! I can see indeed how sunglasses is less emotionally charged than race issues. =)

Comment: My comment was somewhere between the sentiment Michael expressed, and actual surprise at the clarity of the formulation: frequently people who teach statistics don't manage to express things nearly that well (so even if it WAS a homework problem, it was a rather well-written one!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches:

#### Exact

Define

- $n=20345$ (number of gamblers)
- $g = 11393$ (number who wear sunglasses)
- $s = 73$ (sample size of $s$ **distinct** gamblers)
- $X = \mbox{Random number of the sampled gamblers who wear sunglasses}$
- $\theta$ = integer threshold ($\theta = 45$)

Then 
$$P[X\geq \theta] = \sum_{k=\theta}^{s} \frac{{g \choose k}{n-g \choose s-k}}{n \choose s} \approx \boxed{0.1966}$$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%2811393+choose+k%29%28%2820345-11393%29+choose+%2873-k%29%29%2F%2820345+choose+73%29%2C+k%3D45..73

#### Gaussian approximation

Assume the number of gamblers $n$ is so large that independently sampling from them, equally likely over all gamblers, is **unlikely to produce repetitions of the same sampled gambler**.  So we can model $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^s$ as i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with $p=P[X_i=1]=0.56$ (the probability of sampling a sunglass-wearer), and $X=\sum_{i=1}^s X_i$.

$$P\left[\sum_{i=1}^s X_i \geq \theta \right] = ??$$

$$ \sigma = \sqrt{p(1-p)} = 0.4964, s = 73, \theta = 45$$
Then 
\begin{align}
P\left[\sum_{i=1}^s X_i \geq \theta \right] 
&= P\left[ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^s (X_i-0.56)}{\sigma \sqrt{s}} \geq \frac{\theta - 0.56 s}{\sigma \sqrt{s}}\right]\\
&\approx Q\left(\frac{\theta - 0.56 s}{\sigma \sqrt{s}}\right)\\
& \approx 0.1657
\end{align}

Of course you can fudge the numbers a bit with a **continuity correction** 
\begin{align}
P\left[\sum_{i=1}^s X_i \geq \theta \right] 
&= P\left[\sum_{i=1}^s X_i \geq \theta - 0.5 \right] \\
&= P\left[ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^s (X_i-0.56)}{\sigma \sqrt{s}} \geq \frac{\theta - 0.5 - 0.56 s}{\sigma \sqrt{s}}\right]\\
&\approx Q\left(\frac{\theta - 0.5 - 0.56 s}{\sigma \sqrt{s}}\right)\\
& \approx \boxed{0.1967}
\end{align}
We see that, with the continuity correction, the approximation is close to the exact answer.

Comment: I am always amazed when continuity corrections seem to be so accurate.  (Of course, I am a bit suspicious:  Perhaps the example numbers given in the problem are chosen so that a continuity correction works well?)

Comment: Thank you.  To interpret this, the P is the probability that a non-suspect sample produced the value of theta?  So we would say that the probability that we would get this value is about 1 in 5?  To be non-suspect we expect what more like 1 in 2?

Comment: About $1$ in $5$, yes.  You can decide to be suspicious or not, but then you would be falsely accusing 1 in 5 people.  I use $\theta = 45$ because $45/73 = 0.6164 \approx 0.62$.  It is also useful to plot the $p$-value versus $\theta$ to get some more intuition.

Comment: Right. Theta is 45 in this example.  I like your approach, I am just wondering if there is a standard value which we should expect.  So 1 in 5 should produce this result. But what is some justifiable expected number?  Like so I could say to the company, "Your results seem not random because we expect a random sample to give a value that should show up 1 in 2 whereas you get 1 in 5."  Something like that?  

Maybe I am looking for something that doesn't exist?

Comment: I googled “p value threshold interpretation” and found a variety of links that discuss this. It seems a threshold of $0.05$ (1 in 20) is standard, as is $0.01$ and $.005$. With these thresholds, a value of $0.196$ would not be considered low enough to reject the hypothesis that samples were fair.

Comment: Thanks, Michael.  I was unsure whether you were calculating a p-value or not. As I said, statistics is not really my field. I appreciate your time.